# "wp_enqueue_style();" don't load new edited style

Tags: php, css, wp-enqueue-style

First, sorry my english. I am using Local by flywheel to manager my site files and my wordpress version is 4.9.4.

Here is the problem, When I use

```
 wp_enqueue_style('wharever', get_stylesheet_uri());
```

To load style.css at the first time with a just simple content inside:

```
body { color: orange; }
```

Everything is just fine, and we have a page with everything in orange text, but when I change the style.css body color to green (or whatever), they just don't change, and always are orange.

PS.: in wp_enqueue_style, I changed the version parameter and he changes, but only at the first time and stuck with the first color I put for the version that was put.

If this is a feature of wordpress, how can I turn this off? This don't see quite useful know that we can't change style.css at will just to test without change version.

Comment: This is caused by your browser caching the stylesheet. Nothing to do with WordPress. When you add a different `?ver=` to the url, it thinks it's a different stylesheet and reloads it. You can also "force refresh"; usually ctrl+f5 or apple+f5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution is to use `filemtime` for the cachebusting, so that the last modified timestamp is used as the querystring variable.

This has the advantage that of still using the browser cache, and yet, a new file is served when the file is actually changed because the querystring changes. eg.

```
$lastmodtime= filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory().'/style.css');
wp_enqueue_style('whatever', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), $lastmodtime);
```

Comment: Great idea.  This way it still safely uses caching when the file hasn't changed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is a caching problem.  To get around this I append a random string to the stylesheet uri that discourages the browser from caching it.

First you need a random string.  I use this simple function to generate one.

`function randomAlphaNumeric($length) {
    $pool = array_merge(range(0,9), range('a', 'z'),range('A', 'Z'));
    $key='';
    for($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $key .= $pool[mt_rand(0, count($pool) - 1)];
    }
    return $key;
}`

Now just use it in your enqueue like this:

`wp_enqueue_style('wharever', get_stylesheet_uri().'?random='.randomAlphaNumeric(5));`

Comment: or you can just `wp_enqueue_style( 'wharever', get_stylesheet_uri() . '?v=' . time(), array(), $theme_version );` since the time always changing.

Comment: @YamiOdymel That is much simpler. I really like majick's solution because it allows caching if the stylesheet hasn't been modified. His answer deserves more upvotes ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can change your

```
 wp_enqueue_style('wharever', get_stylesheet_uri());
```

to

```
 wp_enqueue_style('wharever', get_stylesheet_uri(),  array(), time(), 'all');
```

And it will start working just fine.